# How to stop UIBarButtonItem text from truncating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, truncate

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` in a Navigation Bar with the text title "Save". When I transition to a fullscreen `UIPopoverController` and then dismiss it, the text in my UIBarButtonItem gets truncated to "S..e". For all other segues and views I have no problem when returning.

I've tried manually changing the width and setting "possibleTitles" to include long words but I can't stop the truncation.

I'm using a custom font if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to init your UIBarButtonItem with a custom view.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:yourView];
```

Just make sure your custom view has the right frame (e.g. for an UILabel ,wide enough to not truncate its content). Things should work fine.

Comment: This seems to be the only way to do it correctly. I was also able to achieve this result by adding a space " " to the end of my word. Frustrating that you need to resort to little hacks or excessive code to fix issues that shouldn't even exist. 

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps helpful, but a `UIBarButtonItem` with a custom view (ex: `UILabel`) that is inserted into a `UIToolbar` can take on the intrinsic size of its contents as long as `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` is set to `false`. I believe this may work for `UINavigationBar` too:

```
private let barButtonLabel: UIBarButtonItem = {
    let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return UIBarButtonItem(customView: label)
}()
```